# Extract only required variable from Response - Angular 7

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular7

I have the following interface

```
interface Employee{name?:string;id?:string;role?:string;}
```

I Have a Response like this

```
{
   "name": "John",
   "id": "ID77777",
   "role": "Engineer",
   "bloodType": "O+ve",
   "placeOfDeployment": "NY"
}
```

I want to extract only the member variables of Interface.So after i am done with the mapping i should get

```
{
   "name": "John",
   "id": "ID77777",
   "role": "Engineer"
}
```

Comment: So what you want is when you get the response with all keys, just display the required ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use lodash which has `pick` function or here's vanilla js with same result.

```
const res = {"name": "John","id": "ID77777","role": "Engineer","bloodType": "O+ve","placeOfDeployment": "NY"};

const user = ["name", "id", "role"].reduce((acc, key) => {
  acc[key] = res[key];
  return acc;
}, {})
```

Note: handle case where res has missing keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can use object destructing

```js
const response = {
  "name": "John",
  "id": "ID77777",
  "role": "Engineer",
  "bloodType": "O+ve",
  "placeOfDeployment": "NY"
}
// this will extract name,id,role property from response
const {name,id,role} = response;
// create a new object and assign those properties
let obj = {
  name,
  id,
  role
};
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ts-transformer-keys](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-transformer-keys), which enables you to obtain keys of given type.

```
import { keys } from 'ts-transformer-keys';    

const keysOfEmployee = keys<Employee>();
const response = {
  "name": "John",
  "id": "ID77777",
  "role": "Engineer",
  "bloodType": "O+ve",
  "placeOfDeployment": "NY"
};

const result = {};
keysOfEmployee.forEach(k => result[k] = response[k]);
```